# How to hide default binding value in Spring input tag?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I've used Spring form tag in my jsp.

```
    <form:form modelAttribute="myAttribute" method="POST"
        action="/doSomething" >

        <form:input path="name" type="text" value="" />
.
.
```

Now my modelAttribute already contains a value for "name" and hence I get a textbox with the value already specified in it.

But I don't want to show that value to the user. I want the user to enter a new value in the textbox.

How can I hide the binding value from being shown inside the textbox?
Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the model attribute's `name` property to the empty string in the controller, before displaying the form for the first time.

That way, if the user submits the form with a validation error, the form will be redisplayed with the form field pre-populated with the value he entered.